# How to Navigate to a dynamically generated url when the data comes from a consumer?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm sharing data between the parent component (`App`) and its child (`MyClass`) through React context provider and consumer.
The child component receives some data, and needs to send it to the server to get back the corresponding URL and then navigate to it using `generateLink(context)` in the following code..

How is it possible to **make that button `Go to page` enabled only after generateLink returned a response, and navigate to that link?**

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './MainContent';

class MyClass extends React.Component {

    generateLink(context){
        // Access to db, get the url, and only then navigate to the url
        // The Api call is working, just removed it for space.

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    <div className="container">
                            {context.chosenItems.map((item) =>
                                <div key={item} className="combination-object">
                                    <button>Item : {item} </button>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        <button onClick={this.generateLink.bind(this, context)}>
                            Go to page
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default MyClass
```

I created a router and some route such as `<Route path="/:uniqueUrl" exact component={MyPage} />`

And a MyPage component such as this:

```
function MyPage({match}){

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(match)
    })

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>combination page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default MyPage
```

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect react-router to your `MyClass` component. You can do this using the `useHistory` hook. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory.

Once your http request is returned from the backend you can call `history.push('/' + results.uniqueUrl)`. results being the response from your API call.

Comment: you can see in my question that I created a route already. I just dont know where to call that history.push function, and how to wait for backend response before doing this

Comment: Okay, so this is more about creating an API request to your back-end then. What are you using for the back-end? You need some sort of API that you can call using HTTP requests. Usually it looks something like this `fetch('/api-route').then((results) => { doSomething() })`

Comment: Hi, No you got me wrong, I do have an api call that's working inside generate links. I just dont know how to update the button with what i said

Comment: you call `history.push` in the callback from your API request with the unique url returned by the API request